# Need to paste Input on multiple sheets Excel, vba

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

[Problem with referencing back to sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4gCY.png)I have a workbook with 37 sheets. Each sheet requires the user's name.
I have a inputbox for them to put in their name, however it only posts on the active sheet. I have tried referencing back to the cell it fills from the macro but it wont reference.
Here is the code

```
Sub Name()
    Set wsDst = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Sheets(2).Range("B16").Value = inputbox("Please type your first name and last intial.", "Name")
End Sub
```

Now if I go to Sheet3 and try `='Sheet2!B16`
that is exactly what shows in cell B16.

The main issue is that the user's name will not always be in B16
Sheet4 is B18.

I know this is probably an easy fix for most, however I am still learning all the syntax's and honestly have used codes others have posted and been able to edit them to my needs.

Comment: Hi, it's not clear what the issue is. How would you solve it manually?

Comment: Then, use `Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B18").Value = inputbox("Please type your first name and last intial.", "Name")` instead your existing line... What do you want to accomplish, in fact?

Comment: I am trying to have it where the user types their name into the input box. Which then fills in a specific cell on multiple sheets. So sheet1 the cell is b16. Sheet2 b16. Sheet3 is b18. And sheet4 is b17. I dont care how many times I have to repeat the code. The main thing is I want the user to be able to type their name 1 time.

Comment: Formula is enough. Why VBA ? If `Sheets(2).Range("B16")` is the first range where the input will be then just enter  `=Sheet2!B16` in all ranges on other sheets. Anyway, you will have to type those ranges in the code.

Comment: As Naresh suggested, I think the same. Put a formula to whatever cell in the sheet where you want the name appear. The same formula `=Sheet2!B16`. For example : in Sheet3 the name should appear in cell B18, then put that formula in cell B18. Sheet4 the name should appear in B17, then put that formula in B17, and so on. Except the main issue is that you want the user's name in Sheet2 will not always be in B16.

Comment: When I try to do =Sheet2!B16 on Sheet3 in cell B18. it shows the formula only. ( Added a photo to OP to show what happens when i try to use that formula.) Sheet2 has been renamed to Closed Claim.

Comment: Instead of value formula is displayed? Have you switched the worksheet view mode to "Formula Display"?...  Try pressing **Ctrl+grave accent (`)** (key before 1 on the top left) ... [Refer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-in-excel-1798d9d5-842a-42b8-9c99-9b7213f0040f)